# Make navbar retain the same position regardless of monitor size

Tags: html, css

I need to position my navigation bar in the same position of the page regardless of monitor size. I'm using the same position scheming as another div which position is universal but when applied the position is off for different sized monitors.

I have tried switching to the positioning to relative, but the same effect still occurs.

```css
    @import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css');

#panel {
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 320px;
    height: 515px;
    background: #191919;
}

.tab {
    background-color: #555;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    top: 16%;
}

.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 23.8px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
}

.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
   

        <div id="game">
      <div class="tab">
           <button class="active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></button>
           <button><i class="fas fa-keyboard"></i></button>
           <button><i class="fas fa-palette"></i></button>
           <button><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></button>
           <button><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></button>
         </div>
        <div id="panel"></div>
     </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add associated HTML? This will help debug this faster.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. Perhaps two screenshots of current and expected behaviour will be a great help.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the div with class `tab` has to be at a same distance from black box all the time? or same distance from window top?

Comment: Question  not clear, Code snippet not helping

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
.navbar
{
    position: fixed;
}
```